# What are the drawbacks of taking this window/aisle solo seat - 71A on Boeing 777-300ER?

Tags: aircraft, seating

I've got an LA to Hong Kong flight coming up and I've never flown for that long before. Flying on boeing 777-300ER. Btw I'm not asking about window vs aisle, I definitely want an aisle seat. However it appears 71A is both window and aisle. This is the basis for my inquiry, to confirm that the window addition only adds benefit to the situation and does not take away from the aisle characteristics.

I'm looking for an aisle seat so 1) I can stretch my legs out 2) get to the bathroom and 3) walk around if I need to 4) minimize exposure to loud noise (engines/machines) or bad smell. Right now I have seat 69G, it's in the aisle and could possibly be bumped into by people walking by. But it works for all criteria I mentioned.

Having a window view would be an added bonus, would seat 71A have any extra exposure to loud noise or bad smell? It is closer to a bathroom, do bathrooms smell on long haul flights?

SeatGuru says "seats in close proximity to a bathroom can be bothersome," what are the common bothersome issues people express due to sitting by a bathroom?

[image]

It almost seems like I'd be able to get the same benefits I want from an aisle seat but also the view?

Would sound be louder in this window seat?

Comment: Welcome to travel.SE.  First off seat configuration, aircraft maintenance(smell), passenger niceness, noise levels are entirely airline and route dependent.  *SeatGuru says seats in close proximity to a bathroom can be bothersome, what do they mean by this?* - that would be an opinion offered by someone and can probably only be explained by that someone.  With all this in mind I'd recommend reviewing the [help page](http://travel.stackexchange.com/help) and editing your question so your limit the scope, the number of questions, and finally ask them so that the answer isn't opinion based.

Comment: Thank you, I edited the above to be a little more specific and I don't think there's anything opinion based anymore. I think the picture of the seating representation makes the question specific enough to be answered and also pertain to anyone else looking for 'solo seat' information

Comment: What airline is this?

Comment: "It almost seems like I'd be able to get the same benefits I want from an aisle seat but also the view?" — I do not understand how you would get any of the benefits of an aisle seat if you picked seat 70A.

Comment: I think you mean 71A/72A, on the picture 70A is typically the kind of seat you'd want to avoid in your case.

Comment: If you mean 71A, then I understand the question. The seat map looks as if there was an aisle between 71A and 71C. This is of course not the case in reality. Seats 71A and 71C are next to each other.

Comment: Wow I'm sorry, definitely meant 71A, edited it above. Flying on Cathay Pacific.

Comment: http://www.iflybusiness.com/airlines/Eva-Airways/Boeing-777-300ERpopup.jpg <- Here is a better map that shows the actual seat arrangement.

Comment: @JukkaSuomela thank you very much, why would row 72 be missing from that photo?

Comment: Some airlines block out the last row of economy for crew rest areas, others to avoid passenger complains because the last row doesn't always recline fully, or just to avoid the number of passengers going over the limit of needing another member of staff, could be any of those

Comment: Where it tapers like that, you may find the seat misaligned to the one in front. May be there will be a bit of extra pitch to compensate. 70 C/H in that diagram are likely to stick out so may get bumped.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think the diagram you posted is misleading, I am a qualified cabin crew for 777-300 and all other variations of 777, the last seat in the diagram shows an empty space in the middle which I think is not correct. Out of experience these seats which are located at the end of the aircraft next to the L5 door (71+72 A+C) have limited space due to the shape of the aircraft as it becomes narrower at the aft of the aircraft, hence they make them two seats only instead of three, same thing also happens in 747s. Here is a diagram to show you what I mean:

[image: aft]

Bottom line, window seat is still a window seat, aisle seat still an aisle seat.

Please note: seat layout and numbering is totally different from one airline to another, so I am talking out of experience since I am not familiar with the specific airline's layout and seat numbering.

Comment: Hi, did you look at the picture I provided? The seat appears to be both an aisle seat and a window seat. I plan to be awake for a lot of the trip, but definintely want to be able to get up or stretch my legs (i don't mean leave them in the aisle because you are right that could be dangerous, but just extended them back and forth for a bit because I'm tall)

Comment: It's a window seat, there's no gap between A/C and H/J, that's just an odd seat-map artefact not coping with the narrowing of the aircraft body towards the tail

Comment: I sat on this row on an Emirates 777-300 ER; there are only two seats. They are adjacent, you are missing the middle seat; in that its now an aisle seat.  This is great if you are traveling with your spouse as its just you two ... although that might be a negative for some.

Answer (score 10):

*(Yes, this is late (he's presumably been to Hong Kong and back by now) but it popped up in the sidebar and no one explained "why")*

The difference between this:

[image: checkin]

And this:

[image: aft]

Is that the first one came from your carrier's online booking system and it has to:

- be adaptable to many aircraft configurations
- work with almost any browser, even the old ones
- be interactive with the user

To accomplish all the above, these seating plans are usually implemented as tables which means the rows and columns have to line up, just like a spreadsheet.

The second picture is not interactive and is a very accurate representation of the seat locations.

Rows 71 and 72 are 2-3-2 rows instead of 3-3-3 rows. The aircraft is getting a lot narrower back there and the airlines ran out of squeeze space.

Advantages of those rows (if you have a window seat) is you are not pushed up against the window - there is space for your bag between the seat and the wall.

Disadvantages of those rows are you may not have any recline - the seat may hit the wall. And the aisle has no more legroom than a middle seat as it is basically in the middle of the row in front of it. The aisle itself cuts through the space where the 3rd seat would normally be.

And as most airlines serve meals front to back, you will probably be left with the "Would you like fish, or fish?" choice. Cold.

With apologies to the cabin crew here, the back rows are usually the nastiest ones on the flight. Unless, of course, the bulkhead row has 3 fussy babies in it.

Answer (score 2):

I am not convinced "seats in close proximity to a bathroom can be bothersome," is entirely a matter of opinion and since not answered above offer some reasons. I suppose these may not bother some people but I do see a difference between seats close to a toilet and those not, regardless of whether an individual's assessment of these is favourable or adverse.

Smell is definitely one, though by no means on all flights. I’ve known one plane delayed while cleaners were brought back on board.

There is more activity and irregular noise, so distracting for anyone trying to concentrate or sleep.

There will usually be crowding at times, so perhaps then difficult to access the overhead storage (of which there may be less anyway).

Congestion  might also lead to the odd nudge of aisle passengers and also prevent them stretching their legs into the aisle.

The toilets may form a bulkhead such that the row of seats immediately adjacent and facing the bulkhead does not have any space underneath a row in front. There may be some compensation from not have a seat back reclining into one (specially at meal times for large people) etc but for a tall person even the few extra inches that a bulkhead row might offer may not, on a long flight, compensate for the reduced legroom.

On board entertainment may be less 'personal' (no screen on the back of a seat in front) and a platform for meal trays may be less convenient to set up and take down. Some aircraft (including the Cathay Pacific 777-300ER in this question) do offer personal entertainment screens in some or all bulkhead seats, but these are usually either [mounted to the bulkhead](https://c1.staticflickr.com/3/2897/14094263117_25bcaa6726.jpg) or fold out from a compartment in the armrest. In cases where a flight attendant [jump seat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jump_seat) is mounted on the bulkhead, though, personal entertainment screens are less likely to be present.

In the particular case of 71A on a [Cathay Pacific 777-300ER](http://www.seatguru.com/airlines/Cathay_Pacific_Airways/Cathay_Pacific_Airways_Boeing_777-300ER_A.php), the seat is close to the aft lavatories, but it is in front of the lavs rather than behind them, so it's not a bulkhead seat.

Comment: Oh, yeah, it doesn't bother me at all. If someone wants to know who wrote it, they can just look at the edit history. :)